# How to locate XX st/nd/rd/th using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a date (or dates) in a string. I feel like this should be really simple, and I'm just missing something, but unfortunately I'm not that experienced with regex.

My regex is:

```
lookup = re.findall("[0123456789]+st|[0123456789]+nd|[0123456789]+rd|[0123456789]+th", userInput, re.IGNORECASE)
for group in lookup:
   print(group)
```

With the output of "3rd, 5th, 21st" ideally being 3rd, 5th, 21st in separate groups. However, if I don't put [0123456789] before EACH st, nd, rd, th, it ends up only matching properly with things like 21st (as it considers the [] to be part of the first | option only)

Is there a simpler and better way to set this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group the suffixes:

```
lookup = re.findall("[0-9]+(?:st|[nr]d|th)", userInput, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yXelkg/1)

Note you need to use a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, if you want to get the right output with `re.findall`. Also, just in case, if you want to  only match whole "words", add `\b` word boundaries around the pattern, `r"\b[0-9]+(?:st|[nr]d|th)\b"`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/q0dRRu):

```
import re
rx = r"[0-9]+(?:st|[nr]d|th)"
s = "April, 23rd June 1st May 2nd"
print(re.findall(rx, s, flags=re.I))
# => ['23rd', '1st', '2nd']
```

Comment: Right, that worked. And that demo you linked was very clear.
I'll accept this as the answer when I can (because I can't yet lol)
Thank you!